NavigationStack on Mac not showing title and back button
I'm creating a menu bar app, but cannot get navigation to work.
NavigationStack with SwiftUI as interface will show a header with back button and title for navigation, see below.

However, if run with AppKit, no header, back button and title is shown, therefore no way to navigate, see below.

Both cases use the same SwiftUI code:
struct MenuItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var items: [MenuItem]?

    static let submenu1 = MenuItem(name: "submenu1")

    static let example1 = MenuItem(name: "menu1", items: [concert1])
    static let example2 = MenuItem(name: "menu2", items: [concert1])
}

struct OtherView: View {
    var menuItem: MenuItem
    
    init(menuItem: MenuItem) {
        self.menuItem = menuItem
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(menuItem.items ?? []) { item in
                    NavigationLink(item.name, destination: Text(item.name))
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle(menuItem.name)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    let items: [MenuItem] = [.example1, .example2]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(item.name, destination: OtherView(menuItem: item))
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("title")
        }

    }
}

One project is created with AppKit's NSStatusItem: AppDelegate code to add status menu:
@main
class MainApp: NSObject {
    let contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: MainView())

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        contentView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

        let menuItem = NSMenuItem()
        menuItem.view = contentView
        let menu = NSMenu()
        menu.addItem(menuItem)
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        statusItem.menu = menu
        statusItem.button?.title = "A"
    }
}

The other one is created with "SwiftUI" as the interface, under MenuBarExtra:
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra {
            MainView()
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}

Is there any special setting to enable the header?
Couldn't find anything related to this issue.
Tried adding .toolbar(.visible) and .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(false), still not showing up.
This question is similar, but I can confirm that it's not a color issue as the entire header is absent.

"Both cases use the same SwiftUI code" so what is the difference? What do you mean by "with Storyboard as interface"? Please show a [mcve].

Try using only one NavigationStack instead of nesting them. If need be use NavigationStack(path: ...)

I've updated my code snippet to include minimal reproducible code. The SwiftUI part is the same code, but one uses MenuBarExtra and the other uses NSHostingView inside NSStatusItem. Using only one NavigationStack did not make the navigation bar show up, unfortunately.

AFAIK, these „interfaces“ are commonly called AppKit- and SwiftUI-lifecycle

did you try removing the NavigationStack from OtherView?

Having inspected the view hierarchy created by SwiftUI's MenuBarExtra, the title seems to be "native" to SwiftUI. It does not use any AppKit components. You could consider this as a unique feature of a .window style MenuBarExtra.
It is still possible to do something similar (but not exactly the same) with a NSStatusItem. You can wrap wrap the SwiftUI view in an NSPanel with a .. This will give it a title bar and a back button.

Here is some example code that shows an NSWindow from an NSStatusItem. Instead of creating an NSWindow, edit StatusBarMenuWindowController.init to create an NSPanel with .utilityWindow style instead.
init(statusItem: NSStatusItem?, contentViewController: NSViewController) {
    self.statusItem = statusItem
    
    let window = NSPanel(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 344, height: 320),
        styleMask: [.titled, .fullSizeContentView, .utilityWindow],
        backing: .buffered,
        defer: false,
        screen: statusItem?.button?.window?.screen
    )
    
    window.isMovable = false
    window.level = .statusBar
    window.contentViewController = contentViewController
    window.titlebarSeparatorStyle = .shadow
    
    super.init(window: window)
    
    window.delegate = self
    setupContentSizeObservation()
}

Then you can pass a NSHostingController into this window controller.
Full code:
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    let contentView = NSHostingController(rootView: MainView())
    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)

    private var windowController: StatusBarMenuWindowController?

    @objc func toggleUIVisible(_ sender: Any?) {
        if windowController == nil || windowController?.window?.isVisible == false {
            showUI(sender: sender)
        } else {
            hideUI()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func hideUI() {
        windowController?.close()
    }

    func showUI(sender: Any?) {
        if windowController == nil {
            windowController = StatusBarMenuWindowController(
                statusItem: statusItem,
                contentViewController: contentView
            )
        }
        
        windowController?.showWindow(sender)
    }
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        // no sizing options and set preferredContentSize, because this is what StatusBarMenuWindowController depends on
        contentView.sizingOptions = []
        contentView.preferredContentSize = .init(width: 200, height: 200)

        statusItem.button?.title = "A"
        statusItem.button?.action = #selector(toggleUIVisible(_:))
    }
}

struct MenuItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var items: [MenuItem]?

    static let submenu1 = MenuItem(name: "submenu1")

    static let example1 = MenuItem(name: "menu1", items: [submenu1])
    static let example2 = MenuItem(name: "menu2", items: [submenu1])
}

struct OtherView: View {
    var menuItem: MenuItem
    
    var body: some View {
        // don't put another NavigationStack here!
        List {
            ForEach(menuItem.items ?? []) { item in
                NavigationLink(item.name) {
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(menuItem.name)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    let items: [MenuItem] = [.example1, .example2]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(item.name) {
                        OtherView(menuItem: item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("title")
        }

    }
}

// --------------- StatusBarMenuWindowController.swift -----------------

//
//  StatusBarMenuWindowController.swift
//  CustomStatusBarWindow2
//
//  Created by Gui Rambo on 02/02/21.
//

import Cocoa
import os.log

final class StatusBarMenuWindowController: NSWindowController {
    
    private let log = OSLog(subsystem: String(describing: StatusBarMenuWindowController.self), category: String(describing: StatusBarMenuWindowController.self))
    
    let statusItem: NSStatusItem?
    
    var windowWillClose: () -> Void = { }

    init(statusItem: NSStatusItem?, contentViewController: NSViewController) {
        self.statusItem = statusItem
        
        let window = NSPanel(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 344, height: 320),
            styleMask: [.titled, .fullSizeContentView, .utilityWindow],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false,
            screen: statusItem?.button?.window?.screen
        )
        
        window.isMovable = false
        window.level = .statusBar
        window.contentViewController = contentViewController
        window.titlebarSeparatorStyle = .shadow
        
        super.init(window: window)
        
        window.delegate = self
        setupContentSizeObservation()
    }
    
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    private var eventMonitor: EventMonitor?
    
    /// Posting this notification causes the system Menu Bar to stay put when the cursor leaves its area while over a full screen app.
    private func postBeginMenuTrackingNotification() {
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().post(name: .init("com.apple.HIToolbox.beginMenuTrackingNotification"), object: nil)
    }
    
    /// Posting this notification reverses the effect of the notification above.
    private func postEndMenuTrackingNotification() {
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().post(name: .init("com.apple.HIToolbox.endMenuTrackingNotification"), object: nil)
    }
    
    override func showWindow(_ sender: Any?) {
        postBeginMenuTrackingNotification()
        
        // Nasty, but necessary so that when our menu window shows up,
        // other windows from Menu Bar items go away.
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)

        repositionWindow()
        
        window?.alphaValue = 1
        
        super.showWindow(sender)
        
        startMonitoringClicks()
    }
    
    private func startMonitoringClicks() {
        eventMonitor = EventMonitor(mask: [.leftMouseDown, .rightMouseDown], handler: { [weak self] event in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.close()
        })
        eventMonitor?.start()
    }
    
    override func close() {
        postEndMenuTrackingNotification()
        
        NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()
        NSAnimationContext.current.completionHandler = {
            super.close()
            
            self.eventMonitor?.stop()
            self.eventMonitor = nil
        }
        window?.animator().alphaValue = 0
        NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Positioning relative to status item
    
    private struct Metrics {
        static let margin: CGFloat = 5
    }
    
    @objc func repositionWindow() {
        guard let referenceWindow = statusItem?.button?.window, let window = window else {
            os_log("Couldn't find reference window for repositioning status bar menu window, centering instead", log: self.log, type: .debug)
            self.window?.center()
            return
        }
        
        let width = contentViewController?.preferredContentSize.width ?? window.frame.width
        let height = contentViewController?.preferredContentSize.height ?? window.frame.height
        var x = referenceWindow.frame.origin.x + referenceWindow.frame.width / 2 - window.frame.width / 2
        
        if let screen = referenceWindow.screen {
            // If the window extrapolates the limits of the screen, reposition it.
            if (x + width) > (screen.visibleFrame.origin.x + screen.visibleFrame.width) {
                x = (screen.visibleFrame.origin.x + screen.visibleFrame.width) - width - Metrics.margin
            }
        }
        
        let rect = NSRect(
            x: x,
            y: referenceWindow.frame.origin.y - height - Metrics.margin,
            width: width,
            height: height
        )
        
        window.setFrame(rect, display: true, animate: false)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Auto size/position based on content controller
    
    private var contentSizeObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    override var contentViewController: NSViewController? {
        didSet {
            setupContentSizeObservation()
        }
    }
    
    private var previouslyObservedContentSize: NSSize?
    
    private func setupContentSizeObservation() {
        contentSizeObservation?.invalidate()
        contentSizeObservation = nil
        
        guard let controller = contentViewController else { return }
        
        contentSizeObservation = controller.observe(\.preferredContentSize, options: [.initial, .new]) { [weak self] controller, _ in
            self?.updateForNewContentSize(from: controller)
        }
    }
    
    private func updateForNewContentSize(from controller: NSViewController) {
        defer { previouslyObservedContentSize = controller.preferredContentSize }
        
        guard controller.preferredContentSize != previouslyObservedContentSize else { return }
        
        repositionWindow()
    }

}

// MARK: - Window delegate

extension StatusBarMenuWindowController: NSWindowDelegate {
    
    func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        windowWillClose()
    }
    
    func windowDidBecomeKey(_ notification: Notification) {
        statusItem?.button?.highlight(true)
    }
    
    func windowDidResignKey(_ notification: Notification) {
        statusItem?.button?.highlight(false)
    }
    
}

// ---------------------- EventMonitor.swift -------------------------

//
//  EventMonitor.swift
//  CustomStatusBarWindow2
//
//  Created by Guilherme Rambo on 11/02/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Guilherme Rambo. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

// Brought to you by: https://www.raywenderlich.com/450-menus-and-popovers-in-menu-bar-apps-for-macos

public class EventMonitor {
    private var monitor: Any?
    private let mask: NSEvent.EventTypeMask
    private let handler: (NSEvent?) -> Void

    public init(mask: NSEvent.EventTypeMask, handler: @escaping (NSEvent?) -> Void) {
        self.mask = mask
        self.handler = handler
    }

    deinit {
        stop()
    }

    public func start() {
        monitor = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: mask, handler: handler)
    }

    public func stop() {
        if monitor != nil {
            NSEvent.removeMonitor(monitor!)
            monitor = nil
        }
    }
}

